# I cant download native-base

Tags: react-native

I use Node.js v18.9.1 and React Native Expo 6.0.8. When I download Native Base I get system error:

```
D:\Ui-Project\UI-Project>npm install native-base
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ui-project@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from native-base@3.4.21
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"*" from native-base@3.4.21
npm ERR!   node_modules/native-base
npm ERR!     native-base@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-15T14_51_31_860Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm install native-base --legacy-peer-deps
```